# Laravel 4 - Not working on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-4

[image]

I'm trying to setup Laravel 4 with google app engine.

Here's the step on how I setup

Download laravel using composer following the docs step.

Create a app.yaml file with this

```
application: laraveldemo 
version: 1 
runtime: php 
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /favicon\.ico   static_files: public/favicon.ico   upload: public/favicon\.ico

- url: /.*   script: public/index.php
```

and start engine.

And thats what I get, following this http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel-4-on-google-appengine-for-php/

Seriously, I don't know what's the problem, it works fine with MAMP.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to the 'native' session driver. You can switch you driver to 'cookie' and your app will run just fine.